# Can't share site with users even when I have "Full Control"

Tags: development, permissions

I am creating sites dynamically using CSOM in C#.

Part of this process is creating 2 groups, `Members` and `Owners`, which have permission levels `Contribute` and `Full Control` respectively:

[image]

I am in the `Owners` group, so I should have **Full Control**, but when i try to invite another user to that group I am denied that access:

[image]

in fact I also get the same when trying to invite the user to the `Members` group.

Why? What does "Full Control" even mean if I can't invite people to these groups?

I also noticed that if I go into the `Members` group it says I don't have permission to view the membership... What is the point in having full control if it doesn't give me full control?

Answer (score 1):

I had to set the group owner, and I did it with this code

```
public void SetGroupOwner(string groupName, string ownerGroupName)
{
    using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(baseUrl))
    {
        clientContext.Credentials = credentials;
        var web = clientContext.Web;

        var group = web.SiteGroups.GetByName(groupName);
        var groupOwner = web.SiteGroups.GetByName(ownerGroupName);

        group.Owner = groupOwner;
        group.Update();
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    }
}
```

So I set the owner of both groups to `CRMT_TESTWS34 Owners`, meaning that the owners group is owned by itself.

It now seems to work fine.